# ajax success function not being ran jquery - but console says otherwise

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have this code

```
    $('a.like').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var object_id = $(this).data('id');
        var token = $(this).data('token');
        var like = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: '{{URL::to('likes')}}',
            type: 'post',
            data: "object_id="+object_id+"&_token="+token,
            datatype: 'json'
        })
        .done(function(data)
        {
            if (data.success)
            {
                var likes = data.count;
                $(like).removeClass('like').addClass('unlike').attr('title', 'Un-Like this Object');
                $(like).next('i').removeClass('not-liked').addClass('liked');
                $(like).next('span').text(likes);
            }
        });         
    });
```

for some reason my `if (data.success)` is not being ran. I have done `console.log(data)` and I get the following

`{"success":true,"count":1}`

I have also console logged the `like` variable and it returns the right element on the page. Not sure what the issue is. Here is the element before the ajax is ran.

```
<a data-token="7183FdwgLl23Nfq9heOdMYEjmqe9ELtGXCrxUpbu" data-id="92" class="like" title="Like this Object" href="#"><i class="fa fa-heart not-liked"></i>&nbsp;<span class="count">0</span></a>
```

P.S. - when it is posted, everything runs smooth server-side and it returns a proper formatted JSON response.

Comment: I cant understand ur question mere bhai

Comment: The question is, when the server responds back with `data` and i check for `data.success` and it is `true` why doesn't it run my code inside the if statement? and alter my `a` element.

Comment: so when you do a console log immediately above the `if(data.success)` you get proper data shown, but if you run it immediately inside the condition, you don't?

Comment: datatype:'json' should be dataType: 'json'

Comment: This is the response AFTER the `if(data.success)`, same results as before http://snag.gy/vD6ku.jpg

Comment: @progysm - tried and still no result. I am at a loss here. Everything functions except the element changes in the `data.success` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$(this).removeClass('like').addClass('unlike').attr('title', 'Un-Like this Object');
$(this).find('i').removeClass('not-liked').addClass('liked');
$(this).find('span').text(likes);
```

The 'a' tag is wrapping the element "i" and "span", thus next() will not work.

Comment: will try, but it should still change class and attribute for the `a` element.

Comment: hmm, that fixed it. why would that keep the entire change from happening as the first line doesn't rely on a find/next?

Comment: In the code above $(like) was incorrect, thus nothing would've happened.

Answer (score 0):

JSFiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/8uwYS/

(the json part is only to get the good answer).

Updated:

```
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json'
```

and

```
        like.removeClass('like').addClass('unlike').attr('title', 'Un-Like this Object');
        like.find('i').removeClass('not-liked').addClass('liked');
        like.find('span').text(likes);
```

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery's Ajax**: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

You can try listening on the `complete` event if `success` isn't being called.
Also, you have typos.  `type` should be `POST` and `datatype` should be `dataType`.
Similarly, `i` and `span` are children of `like`.

```
$('a.like').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var object_id = $(this).data('id');
    var token = $(this).data('token');
    var like = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: '{{ URL::to('likes') }}',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({"object_id": object_id, "_token": token}),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            like.removeClass('like')
                .addClass('unlike')
                .attr('title', "Unlike this object.");

            like.children('i').removeClass('not-liked').addClass('liked');
            like.children('span').text(data.count);
        }
    });
});
```